# Escaping Dollar sign in Jenkins credentials

Tags: bash, jenkins, yaml

I have `test$001` as a value in Jenkins secret text credentials. Later in pipeline script i'm accessing that value and writing it to yaml file like mentioned below, which is used as K8S configmap.

Problem is with the Dollar sign in the value.

```
environment {
    TEST_CRED=credentials('TEST_CRED')
}
```

script.sh

```
cat << EOF > test.yaml
...
data:
 TEST: ${TEST_CRED}
EOF
```

Expected: `test$001`

Printed: `test$$001` (Note **extra dollar sign** being inserted automatically)

I tried all possibilities to escape this dollar sign, nothing worked.

```
TEST_01: '${TEST_CRED}'
TEST_02: ${TEST_CRED}
TEST_03: '$${TEST_CRED}'
TEST_04: $${TEST_CRED}
TEST_05: "$${TEST_CRED}"
TEST_08: $TEST_CRED
```

Comment: Could you try placing `test\$001` instead of `test$001` in the Jenkins secret text credentials and try to check whether you are getting the correct value. Because as per your test cases, nothing is working, it means while storing the value, Jenkins escaped it with another $ sign so, that Jenkins can handle it.

Comment: @ShubhamVaishnav I tried your suggestion, Now this is what i'm getting `test\$$001`

Answer (score 3):

When storing value in Jenkins secret text credentials, escape the dollar sign. So, `test$001` should actually be *stored* as `test\$001`.

Following works for me:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        MYTEST_CRED=credentials('TEST_CRED')
    }

    stages {
        stage('Special Char') {
            steps {
                sh """
                    cat << EOF > test.yaml
                    Name: test-config
                    Namespace: default
                    data:
                         TEST: ${MYTEST_CRED}
EOF
                """
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is an example when I'm passing a not escaped string to the Jenkins job via parameters. And things are not going my way.

```
// Original and expected value. Works fine with pure groovy
echo env.SECRET_VALUE
test@U$3r

// But this variable in shell is getting messed up

// sh("\$ENV") and sh('$ENV') are using value of shell env variale

sh("echo \$SECRET_VALUE")
test@U$$3r

sh('echo $SECRET_VALUE')
test@U$$3r

// sh("$ENV") and sh("${ENV}") are using value of groovy variables passed to the shell

sh("echo $SECRET_VALUE")
test@Ur

sh("echo ${SECRET_VALUE}")
test@Ur
```

Let's try to fix it

```
env.ESCAPED_SECRET_VALUE = env.SECRET_VALUE.replaceAll(/(!|"|@|#|\$|%|&|\\/|\(|\)|=|\?)/, /\\$0/)

// groovy variable is becoming a bit broken

echo env.ESCAPED_SECRET_VALUE       
test\@U\$3r

// shell env variable is still broken

sh("echo \$ESCAPED_SECRET_VALUE")
test\@U\$$3r

sh('echo $ESCAPED_SECRET_VALUE')
test\@U\$$3r

// But, if we will pass groovy env variable to the shell - it looks good

sh("echo $ESCAPED_SECRET_VALUE")   
test@U$3r

sh("echo ${ESCAPED_SECRET_VALUE}")
test@U$3r
```

If You are using command straight in the `sh(script:"")`, then just pass groovy ESCAPED variable. If You need to invoke shell script file, then try to pass value of this groovy ESCAPED variable as input argument into it

Example:

`sh("./my_super_script.sh $ESCAPED_SECRET_VALUE")`

```
# my_super_script.sh 
#!/bin/bash
SECRET_VALUE=$1
echo $SECRET_VALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a setup as per your requirement and got the desired results.
The setup is shown below with the screenshots,

1. Setup Jenkins secret text credential
   [image]
2. Setup Binding in the Jenkins job
   [image]
3. Configuring the build to create the test.yaml
   [image]
4. Content of test.yaml

```sh
$ cat test.yaml 
...
data:
 TEST: test$001
```

Comment: That's not a pipeline job though, so you can't compare it.

Comment: @MichaelKüller The only key point here is that Jenkins is not escaping it, and we are getting the same value as we have configured. In the case of a pipeline job, way of accessing the secret will change but not the value. So, this can be used to check whether we get the desired results or not.

Comment: I think the problem is not that simple, because I am facing the same problem as well, even in a non pipeline job. I have a Maven Type Job, in which I pass the credential in the Maven Goals and Options field and also there the "$" character is doubled, and I have not found a workaround yet. 
The same behaviour does not show when using it in an "Execute Shell" block, like in your example.